# Log values of query parameters in Spring Data R2DBC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

In [Spring Data R2DBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#r2dbc.getting-started) I can log SQL queries by using

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.r2dbc=DEBUG
```

in the `application.properties`.

However, this doesn't log the actual values that are bound as query parameters.

How can I log the actual values of query parameters in Spring Data R2DBC?

Comment: @harold-l-brown did you try logging.level.org.springframework.data.r2dbc=TRACE ?

Comment: @AbinashGhosh Yes, that didn't print the bindings either. ☹️

Comment: Current Spring versions require a different logger to be set to DEBUG: logging.level.org.springframework.r2dbc=DEBUG

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
 logging:
  level:
    io.r2dbc.postgresql.QUERY: DEBUG # for queries
    io.r2dbc.postgresql.PARAM: DEBUG # for parameters
```

I found it [here](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/blob/main/src/main/java/io/r2dbc/postgresql/client/QueryLogger.java#L27)

Comment: It is also described in the `README.md` now: https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/blob/1a9cb75df519c7c5e8fdb706287a085f5b70c51c/README.md#logging

Comment: Do you happen to know what properties to use in the case of the h2 in-memory database?

Answer (score 5):

For h2 and perhaps other DBs try:

```
logging.level.io.r2dbc.h2=TRACE
```

Answer (score 5):

In SpringBoot v2.7.5 make this:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.r2dbc=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.r2dbc=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use MySQL, you can get a low level network dump of all communication with the database server by setting the driver's log level to `TRACE`.

```
logging.level.ROOT=TRACE
logging.level.dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient=TRACE
```

Example output:

```
19-11-2020 00:03:28.072 TRACE [reactor-tcp-nio-2] d.m.r.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient - [id: 0x9cf29125, L:/127.0.0.1:63807 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:33306] READ: 71B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 01 00 00 01 01 1b 00 00 02 03 64 65 66 00 00 00 |..........def...|
|00000010| 05 4e 4f 57 28 29 00 0c 3f 00 13 00 00 00 0c 81 |.NOW()..?.......|
|00000020| 00 00 00 00 14 00 00 03 13 32 30 32 30 2d 31 31 |.........2020-11|
|00000030| 2d 31 39 20 30 31 3a 30 33 3a 32 38 07 00 00 04 |-19 01:03:28....|
|00000040| fe 00 00 02 00 00 00                            |.......         |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an [r2dbc-proxy](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-proxy) project in [r2dbc](https://github.com/r2dbc) repo that provide exactly what you need.

You can refer to [this article](https://r2dbc.io/2021/04/14/r2dbc-proxy-tips-query-logging) about how to configure the proxy.

Basically you will need to provide a `ConnectionFactory` bean with a proxy on it.

```java
import io.r2dbc.proxy.ProxyConnectionFactory;
import io.r2dbc.proxy.support.QueryExecutionInfoFormatter;
import io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
class ConnectionConfig {

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory original = ...
        QueryExecutionInfoFormatter formatter = QueryExecutionInfoFormatter.showAll();
        return ProxyConnectionFactory.builder(original)
                .onAfterQuery(queryInfo -> log.info(formatter.format(queryInfo)))
                .build();
    }
}
```

And the logging output is like this:

```
Thread:http-nio-8080-exec-3(38) Connection:3 Transaction:{Create:1 Rollback:0 Commit:0}
Success:True Time:5 Type:Statement BatchSize:0 BindingsSize:1
Query:["INSERT INTO test VALUES ($1)"] Bindings:[($1=100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

i have to update source code to log parameterize sql statement in mysql r2dbc .
this is my approach :

```
  Index: src/main/java/dev/miku/r2dbc/mysql/message/client/TextQueryMessage.java
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
diff --git a/src/main/java/dev/miku/r2dbc/mysql/message/client/TextQueryMessage.java b/src/main/java/dev/miku/r2dbc/mysql/message/client/TextQueryMessage.java
--- a/src/main/java/dev/miku/r2dbc/mysql/message/client/TextQueryMessage.java   (revision bdba9eebe79976aa4bb75aa0aad25c7cbbdf4dec)
+++ b/src/main/java/dev/miku/r2dbc/mysql/message/client/TextQueryMessage.java   (revision 1b5e0133cc8d43bfc32133912d9e3589374ae75a)
@@ -20,6 +20,8 @@
 import dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.Parameter;
 import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
 import io.netty.buffer.ByteBufAllocator;
+import org.slf4j.Logger;
+import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
 
 import java.nio.charset.Charset;
@@ -42,6 +44,8 @@
 
     private final Consumer<String> sqlProceed;
 
+    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TextQueryMessage.class);
+
     public TextQueryMessage(List<String> sqlParts, Parameter[] values, Consumer<String> sqlProceed) {
         requireNonNull(sqlParts, "sql parts must not be null");
         requireNonNull(values, "values must not be null");
@@ -64,6 +68,10 @@
         try {
             Charset charset = context.getClientCollation().getCharset();
             return ParamWriter.publish(sqlParts, values).map(sql -> {
+
+                if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
+                    logger.debug("parametered sql statement[{}]",sql);
+                }
                 sqlProceed.accept(sql);
 
                 ByteBuf buf = allocator.buffer(sql.length(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

then change the log level of  TextQueryMessage in  logback-spring.xml:

```
<logger name="dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.message.client.TextQueryMessage" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="async_file"/>
</logger>
```