# Spring Data R2DBC mysql - Log query and query parameter

Tags: mysql, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am using Spring data r2dbc for mysql.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
runtimeOnly 'dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql'
runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
```

I am able to print the query using the below log statement.

> logging.level.org.springframework.r2dbc: DEBUG

Itis only printing the statement but not the query parameter.

Sample log statement,

```
o.s.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient     : Executing SQL statement [select * from project where usr_id = :usrId and start_time BETWEEN :stDate and :endTime]
```

Comment: can you check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972914/log-values-of-query-parameters-in-spring-data-r2dbc

Comment: @GvSharma, logging.level.dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient=TRACE -> prints a lot and very difficult to read the logs